# Grafana for Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, grafana, prometheus, spark-structured-streaming

I followed these steps to setup Prometheus, Graphite Exporter and Grafana to plot metrics for Spark 2.2.1 running Structured Streaming. The collection metrics on this post are quite dated; and does not include any metrics (I believe) that can be used to monitor structured streaming. I am especially interested in the resources and duration to execute the streaming queries that perform various aggregations.

Is there any pre-configured dashboard for spark - I was a little surprised not to find one on https://grafana.com/dashboards 
Which makes me suspect that Grafana is not widely used to monitor metrics for Spark. If that's the case, what works better?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not any dashboard in the oficial Grafana dashboard, but you can check the next Spark dashboard that display metrics collected from Spark applications.

https://github.com/hammerlab/grafana-spark-dashboards